# How to wire ground when the sub-panel is Plug-On Neutral

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, grounding

I need to install a sub-panel in my home. Both the main panel and the sub panel are in the same building. I purchased a Square D Homeline Indoor Plug-On Neutral panel (Model # HOM2040M100PCVP) for this. I plan on using aluminum 2-2-2-4 cable to feed this 100Amp sub-panel from the main panel. 
When I got the new sub-panel home, I discovered that the panel is designed to place the neutral and ground on the same bus bar.  Since this is a sub-panel, I understand that I need to isolate the ground from the neutral. I've purchased two Square D ground bars (Model # PK23GTACP) for this. 
The question is, how do I attach the #4 service ground cable to the sub-panel? Is there some kind of special clamp to attach the service ground cable to the panel body?

Comment: I think people might be missing the point on this question. The neutral busbar is screwed to the box so it is part of the grounded box and in continuity with the ground. There’s not really any way to separate the box from the neutral busbar that I can see so it is not possible to separate the neutral from the ground.

Comment: In most panels (pretty sure in this one, but a quick look at the documents I could easily find was not 100% definitive and I am not a pro) the neutral busbar is screwed to the box but **insulated** from the box. It then has a separate screw to provide grounding (by electrically connecting to the box) **installed if needed**. Sometimes preinstalled, in which case **removed if not needed.**

Answer (score 2):

Install a ground lug in the panel, something [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KKNN8Q), or use a kit [like this one](https://www.superbreakers.net/pk23gtal.html). Just remember, like you said, that the neutral bar has to be isolated from the panel. It'll be on plastic/insulating stand-offs.

[image]

Comment: This will make the job much easier, but know that most modern ground and neutral bars will accept up to a #4 conductor. It just needs to be cut cleanly and the end not buggered up.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I presumed the OP had already tried and failed to stuff a #4 into that grounding bus. ;-) Upvoted your comment, though.